# Не прямая / непрямая речь

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные, терминология

Как правильно?

> Если есть только не прямая / непрямая речь, то точка ставится.

Comment: Кривая (непрямая) речь? А что это? К прямой речи (грамматика) отношения нет. Есть термин "косвенная речь". Но тогда надо его использовать.  Есть еще несобственно-прямая речь.  О чем здесь говорится? НЕПРЯМОЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. Лишённый прямизны; кривой. // Обходной. Ходить непрямыми путями. 2. Лишённый прямоты; неоткровенный; уклончивый. Н. человек. Н. ответ. Суть вопроса неясна, требуется редактирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть вопроса, думаю, ясна: слитно или раздельно пишется слово "не/прямая"?

В словаре Ефремовой:
[непрямой](https://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9)
**3)** ***косвенный***, опосредованный.

Из [научной статьи](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/nekotorye-sposoby-yazykovoy-realizatsii-nesobstvenno-pryamoy-rechi-v-nemetskom-i-russkom-yazykah/viewer) по специальности «Языкознание и литературоведение» (А. В. Боровина, Н. В. Пестова):

> В течение ХХ века многие выдающиеся ученые пытались максимально приблизиться к сути этого многогранного явления с лингвистических и эстетических позиций, что послужило причиной возникновения различных терминов: «пережитая речь», «скрытая речь», «завуалированная речь», «свободная косвенная речь», «несобственно-прямая речь», «несобственная косвенная речь», «несобственная авторская речь», «**непрямая** речь автора», «несобственная речь героя», «**непрямая**», «смешанная», «авторское смешение косвенной и прямой речи», «косвенно прямая», «замещенная прямая», «пересказанная», «фигуральная», «внутренний монолог», «речь как факт», «речь в речи» и т. д.

«Непрямая речь» — книга стихов С. Шестакова.

Так что такой термин (*непрямая речь*), который без противопоставления может писаться слитно, имеется. Считаю, что можно так оформить предложение:

*Если есть только непрямая речь, то точка ставится.*
(Непрямая, то есть косвенная — утверждение.)